# Is it bad to return int for error checking in c++

Tags: c++, error-handling, return

In C many functions return int if they need to let the calling code know if something went wrong in a function call.

C++ has exceptions which do the same thing but more formalized by the language. One advantage (or sometimes disadvantage) of returning an int instead is that you don't force the calling code to address when something has gone wrong, so it can ignore the warning if it doesn't matter in the context

Is it bad practice in C++ to return an int to indicate that something has gone wrong. Additionally, if it is bad practice what are better alternatives.

Comment: Exceptions do not "do the same thing" as error codes. They are two different ways of handling failures. Returning error codes is not a bad practice.

Comment: The answers to this are opinion-based.   Generally speaking, it depends on the nature and criticality of an error.    If a program can't continue unless the error condition (or its set of causes) is corrected then it may be appropriate to throw an exception - since that forces program termination unless the exception is caught and some action is taken to correct the error.   If a program CAN continue despite the error condition, it is appropriate to use a return code, since there would be no harm in forgetting to check if an error has occurred.   So it depends on needs of the application.

Comment: Your question is better suited for [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) sister site of SO. There 'whiteboard questions' are being discussed.

Comment: @Peter "since there would be no harm in forgetting to check if an error has occurred"?  I beg to differ.  _Something_ obviously went wrong.

Comment: On my previous project, we returned error codes often. Throwing an exception was only if the program should be terminated.  That was our policy.  It isn't "good" or "bad", it is just what we did.

Comment: @Eljay: It's bad. C++ was explicitly designed to use exceptions. Constructors in particular cannot return error codes while on the other had exceptions in constructors are carefully designed to unwind exactly those parts of the constructor that have already run.

Comment: @PaulSanders -  plenty of error conditions can be detected and reported by one section of code (e.g. a function) but have no effect on another section of code.   If analysis can confirm that the calling code doesn't need to do anything if a called function indicates an error, then the calling code doesn't need to check the returned error indication.   That's not saying the error condition didn't occur.   It's saying that other code which is unaffected by that error doesn't need to check if that error occurred.

Comment: Yes, but it's incredibly unreliable to permit that, so it's much better to always detect and propagate errors.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it bad practice in C++ to return an int to indicate that something
>   has gone wrong. Additionally, if it is bad practice what are better
>   alternatives.

Yes, it's terrible practice. If there is an error, *always throw an exception*. Unchecked errors are a pointless source of bugs, they work really poorly in certain language constructs like constructors, and they're hard to reason about in generic code.

If the operation succeeded but with some warning, you could consider using an enumeration (not int!) for the warning, although typically such operations can return multiple warnings.

Answer (score 1):

i'd recommend a enum class for errorCodes, that way you do not accidentally mix them up with other errors or some actual int values

e.g.

```
enum class MyResultCode
{
   NoError = 0,
   InternalError,
   DatabaseError,
}
```

as user4581301 suggested, you can add `NumberErrors` as a last enum value and accompany the enum class with some human-readable strings. This way you can log or display a nice error message

Comment: You forgot 'Unknown error" :)

Comment: I also find a `NumberErrors` enum useful to go in as the last entry for reality checks and sizing the string table used to hold human readable error messages.

Comment: Blech, should never have UnknownError :(

Answer (score 0):

One of the main advantages of exceptions is, that you can isolate error handling code from business logic. Say you have a long chain of functions and the last function in the chain has to return an error:

```
int funcA() 
{
    try
    {
        return funcB();
    } 
    catch(...)
    {
        // handle exception
    }
}

int funcB() 
{
    return funcC(); 
}

int funcC() 
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

If an exception is thrown in `funcC` the exception will propagate to the closest `try/catch` block. Since there is not an immediate `try/catch` in `funcC`, all objects created in `funcC` will be destroyed and then it will move to `funcB` to look for a `try/catch` block and the same process will repeat. So by the time we hit the top level caller, the stack will be unwound so all objects created in the stack will be safely disposed of. Basically we handled the exceptional code only in one place `funcA()`. Also by using exceptions, you get contextual information as to what happened, for example:

```
int divide(int a, int b) 
{
    if(b == 0)
    {
        throw "Division by zero error";
    }
    return a / b;
}
```

With custom error codes, you to propagate the error manually all the way to the top so we will end up with error handling code in every layer:

```
// using error codes
int funcA() 
{
    int ret = funcB();
    if(ret == someErrorCode) 
    {
         return someErrorCode;
    }
    else  
    {
         // do some stuff
         return goodValue;
    }
}

int funcB() 
{
    int ret = funcC();
    if(ret == someErrorCode) 
    {
         return someErrorCode;
    }
    else  
    {
         // do some stuff
         return goodValue;
    }
}

int funcC() 
{
    // do some stuff
}
```